# How to prove conservation of energy from a central potential, taking Newton's laws as assumptions?

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

This is an entirely mathematics question, but only with some trivial physics assumptions.

This is a two-body system made into a one-body system by using reduced mass.

$U(r) = -\int_{r_A}^{r}dr'\mathbf{F_1}(\mathbf{r'}).\mathbf{r'} + U(r_A) $

I know that $r_A$ is arbitrary. So,

$U(r_A) = U(r) +\int_{r_A}^{r}dr'\mathbf{F_1}(\mathbf{r'}).\mathbf{\hat{r}'}$ must hold for all $\mathbf{r}$ (or $|\mathbf{r}|$?).

Given it's a central force, $\mathbf{F_1}\propto\mathbf{r}$ and $|\mathbf{F_1}|=f(r)$ and therefore,

$U(r_A) = U(r) +\int_{r_A}^{r}dr'F_1(r')$.

But how does this (mathematically) lead to,

$E = \frac{1}{2}\mu\mathbf{\dot{r}}.\mathbf{{\dot{r}}}+U(r)$

given Newton's second law,

$\mathbf{F_1}=\mu\mathbf{\ddot{r}}$.

I'm looking for the explicit mathematically lines of reasoning and not physics.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to avoid appealing to Newton's second law in order to establish this, i.e. $\mu \ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{F}_1$.

Comment: Apologies. Revised.

Comment: You're asking to prove conservation of energy mathematically, methinks.

Comment: This makes much more sense in the Lagrangian setting.

Comment: take a look at my answer and tell if you are satisfied! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actully derive it using the definition of work.

so we have a central force:
$$
\vec{F}=-\frac{d U}{d r}\hat{r}
$$
let's calculate the work: between to states $S_1$ and $S_2$:
$$
W_{12}=\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{\textrm{dr}}=-\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \frac{d U}{d r}\hat{r}\cdot \vec{\textrm{dr}}
$$
which is obviously:
$$
W_{12}=U(r_1)-U(r_2)
$$
now let's do the same using newton second law $\vec{F}=\mu\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$:
$$
W_{12}=\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \vec{F}\cdot \vec{\textrm{dr}}=\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \mu\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot \vec{\textrm{dr}}=
$$
$$
=\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \mu\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\textrm{dt}=\int_{S_1 \to S_2} \mu\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\cdot \vec{\textrm{dv}}=\frac{1}{2}\mu v_2^2-\frac{1}{2}\mu v_1^2
$$
*(Remark: this demonstration of the work-energy principle can be done in much more mathematical detail in the lagrangian setting, this is mostly an intuitive proof, consult wikipedia:[W-E Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work.E2.80.93energy_principle) for more detail)*

equate:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mu v_2^2-\frac{1}{2}\mu v_1^2 = U(r_1)-U(r_2)
$$
rearrange so all variables of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are on opposite sides:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mu v_2^2+U(r_2) = \frac{1}{2}\mu v_1^2+U(r_1) = \textrm{constant}
$$
so since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are arbitrary this holds for any state,thus we have obtained a constant of the motion, let's call it Energy:
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2+U(r)=\frac{1}{2}\mu \dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}}+U(r)
$$

Comment: Is any assumption required for the "mapping" (if you understand what I mean) between each distinct state and $v$ & $r$?

Comment: Why is the potential a partial derivative when we know that it only depend on $r$?

Comment: sry it's a typo :) no particular assumpion made. only that that the potential is a smooth function (continuos and differentiable)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the physical definitions of kinetic energy as $T = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{r}^2$ where $r = |\vec{r}|$, and total energy as $E = T + U$. Then you can use the fact that a central force is necessarily conservative, and so $\vec{F} = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\hat{r}$, in this case. By Newton's Second Law, by the other hand, you have $\vec{F} = m\ddot{\vec{r}} $. Then all you need to do is to calculate $\frac{dE}{dt}$.

Comment: Why is the potential a partial derivative when we know that it only depend on $r$?